# Weird characters appear in C program

Tags: c

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    int i;
    char zin[100], combinatie[5];
    int combinaties = 0; // variabele aanmaken om later het aantal conbinaties te tellen

    int letters = strlen(combinatie); // Het aantal letters
    printf("Voer de zin in waarin u de lettercombinatie wilt testen: "); // De zin waarin de combinatie getest zal worden
    scanf("%[^\n]", &zin);
    printf("%c", zin);
    int lengteZin = strlen(zin); // De lengte van de zin

    printf("Voer de combinatie in waarop u wilt zoeken: "); // Combinatie waarop gezocht moet worden
    scanf("\n%[^\n]", &combinatie);

    printf("%s\n", zin); // Hier print je de zin
    printf("%s\n", combinatie); // Hier print je de combinatie

    for (i = 0; i < lengteZin; i++) {
        printf("zin \t %c \n", (zin + i));
        if (*(zin + i ) == (*combinatie)) {
            if (*(zin + i + 1) == *(combinatie + 1)) {
                combinaties++;
            }
       }
    }

    // Hierboven in de voor print je de zin letter voor letter uit, ook check je hier op combinaties door gebruik te maken van de astrix "" die voor pointers staan.

    printf("De lettercombinatie '%s' komt %d keer voor", combinatie, combinaties); // Print het uiteindelijke resultaat uit
    return 0;
}
```

I am showing certain letter combinations. You can choose which ones you can see. For example in the sentence `This is a teest seentence` choose the combination `ee` it will tell you it appears 2 times. So it works!

The question now is: *why does it show me weird characters in the console?*

I am trying to do it with pointers.

[image: This is what i mean]

Comment: Does your compiler raise some warning here `printf("%c", zin);`? If not, increase diagnistics level. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra`. You cheat on the `printf` function by promising to pass a `char` but instead you throw a pointer at it. The same is true for `(zin + i)` which causes your output

Comment: Another place where you might get a warning: `int letters = strlen(combinatie);` You do not initialize `combinatie`.

Comment: Okay i found it, i did not use a " * " in front of my -- printf("zin \t %c \n", (zin + i)); -- 

Using -- *(zin + i) -- it works. The only thing thats still left is the weird A at the top on 

line 2

Comment: should be `zin[i]`

Comment: What is `printf("%c", zin);`

Comment: @stark yes it should be, but i am trying to do it with pointers. But i forgot using the astrix... it was a stupid mistake haha. All i am facing right now is the problem on Line 2 from the picture. The weird A at the start of the line

Comment: Line 2 is printed by the line stark and myself mentioned in comments. Same issue there: add a `*`

Comment: Note `if (*(zin + i ) == (*combinatie)){` is equivalent to: `if (zin[i]  == combinatie[0] ){` , which is easier to read, and more common.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get *weird* characters is you pass the array `zin` to `printf` for the `"%c"` format instead of the first character `zin[0]`: in `printf("%c", zin);` and `printf("zin \t %c \n", (zin + i));`

The behavior is actually undefined, which is you case produces *weird* characters, that happen to correspond to the low order byte of the address of `zin[i]`.

Note also that your code can only handle 2 letter strings in `combinatie` and will report 3 occurrences of `ee` in `heeeello!`. You can use the standard function `strstr()` for a more general approach.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char zin[100], combinatie[5];
    int combinaties = 0; // variabele aanmaken om later het aantal conbinaties te tellen

    printf("Voer de zin in waarin u de lettercombinatie wilt testen: "); // De zin waarin de combinatie getest zal worden
    if (scanf("%99[^\n]", zin) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Voer de combinatie in waarop u wilt zoeken: "); // Combinatie waarop gezocht moet worden
    if (scanf("\n%4[^\n]", combinatie) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("%s\n", zin); // Hier print je de zin
    printf("%s\n", combinatie); // Hier print je de combinatie

    for (int i = 0; zin[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("zin \t %c \n", zin[i]);
        if (zin[i] == combinatie[0]) {
            if (zin[i + 1] == combinatie[1]) {
                combinaties++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Hierboven in de voor print je de zin letter voor letter uit, ook check je hier op combinaties door gebruik te maken van de astrix "" die voor pointers staan.

    printf("De lettercombinatie '%s' komt %d keer voor\n", combinatie, combinaties); // Print het uiteindelijke resultaat uit
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers. It is fixed now.

## First

I had a line that didn't do anything. Line 13 `"printf("%c", zin);"`

**This fixed my problem at the start of line 2 of the picture.**

## second

I forgot to use an astrix **(*)** at line 25 of the code `printf("zin \t %c \n", (zin + i));`
in front of `(zin + i));` 
after putting an astrix in front of it. My code was completly fuctional without any problems.

**This fixed my problem from the picture where i circled all the characters**

Comment: Or just use `zin[i]`

Comment: As i said, i am doing it with pointers only, thats why i do not use zin[i].

Comment: It is not a pointer. It is an array name decaying to a pointer expression. If you want to practice pointer usage, you could put the whole compare stuff into a function, taking two `char*` arguments.

Comment: That first line did **not** do nothing. It printed 1 byte of an address as if it was a character which resulted in another garbage character printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
char zin[100]
scanf("%[^\n]", &zin);
printf("zin \t %c \n", (zin + i));
```

zin array has a length of 100, while the string itself has a length less than 100, so the rest contains random values.

Comment: These random values do not matter as they are not touched at all. `zin+i` is an address, not an element in that array.

Comment: @Gerhardh ah, true. I didnt notice it didnt have the asterisk.